# using php-r to call R inside PHP

Tags: php, r

I want to use R inside PHP using [php-r](https://github.com/kachkaev/php-r). As I am very new to PHP, I would be very grateful if anyone guides me on how to install php-r inside xampp and run the same.

I tried putting the PHPR directory inside htdocs and accessed it from php using

```
<?php

use Kachkaev/PHPR/RCore;
use Kachkaev/PHPR/Engine/CommandLineREngine;

$r = new RCore(new CommandLineREngine('/usr/bin/R'));

$result = $r->run(<<<EOF
x = 1
y = 2
x + y
x + z
x - y
EOF
    );

echo $result;
?>
```

This returns an error

> Fatal error: Class 'Kachkaev\PHPR\RCore' not found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/testserver/test.php on line 6

N.B: My R is installed in `/usr/bin/R`

Comment: the R installation location is irrelevant right now. the RCore class isn't loaded, so there's no way for the code to work.

Comment: `composer require kachkaev/php-r` is the easiest way to install php-r

Comment: I never received any feedback regarding the answer I left; did it solve your problem? If it did, marking it as accepted would be appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
use Kachkaev/PHPR/RCore;
use Kachkaev/PHPR/Engine/CommandLineREngine;
```

I suspect you are confusing the `use` statement's purpose. It [imports a namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) into the current code. Accordingly, it uses the [namespace separator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) -- a backslash, not a forward slash:

```
use Kachkaev\PHPR\RCore;
use Kachkaev\PHPR\Engine\CommandLineREngine;
```

Before you can import the namespace, PHP has to be aware of the associated code. The most basic way is to use [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) statements:

```
require /path/to/htdocs/php-r/src/Kachkaev/PHPR/RCore.php
```

Note that these are filesystem paths, not URLs. `require` will throw an error if the file cannot be found, `include` will not.

Most modern projects have an autoloading component such as [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) that will handle this for you though. Once set up, you would simply add this to your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "kachkaev/php-r": "dev-master"
    }
}
```